Include basicConstraints in end-entity certificate generated by step-ca
Is it possible to include the basicConstraints extension in an end-entity certificate generated by step-ca?
I can generate a private/public keypair using the command
step ca certificate {subject} {certfile} {keyfile}

However, the certificate does not include the basicConstraints extension. I understand that if this extension is not included it should be assumed to be equivalent to CA:FALSE, so it wouldn't normally need to be included for an end-entity certificate. However, my use case (uploading own certificate for the web interface of an ASUS router) appears to use this extension to check whether it's an end-entity certificate, so it fails. Any way to override and include this extension?
Edit: I should add that I have tried to make the CA include this extension by default via template file, but this didn't work:
{
    "subject": {{ toJson .Subject }},
    "sans": {{ toJson .SANs }},
{{- if typeIs "*rsa.PublicKey" .Insecure.CR.PublicKey }}
    "keyUsage": ["keyEncipherment", "digitalSignature"],
{{- else }}
    "keyUsage": ["digitalSignature"],
{{- end }}
    "extKeyUsage": ["serverAuth", "clientAuth"],
    "basicConstraints": {
        "isCA": false
    }
}

